# Adding Watermarks To Tiles

Tags: maptiler

You advertise watermarks as being available on your Pro version, when I go through the process to render raster tiles, I don't see this option. Where is the watermark option please?
Thanks
Carl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom watermarks can be added via "-watermark" argument when MapTiler Pro is called on the command-line.

It is documented in the manual (0.5) on page 8, with an example of use:

```
￼maptiler -o tiles -watermark watermark_image.png map.tif
```

We plan to add it into GUI as well - under Advanced options dialog - in a future version of MapTiler (probably version 0.6+). The new versions of MapTiler Pro are provided for free for one year after the purchase.

Comment: Thanks, I have no manual so this explains it (will request one), cheers